# Test merge doesn't show anything to merge from trunk to branch even though trunk has new changes

Tags: svn, merge, version-control, tortoisesvn

Last week I completed the following steps to merge from the trunk to my branch (This was the first merge from the Trunk to the branch):

1. Commit all changes in the branch.
2. Right click in the branches working directory and select TortoiseSVN->merge.
3. Select "Merge a range of revisions" Merge Type.
4. I think I selected a specific range of revisions to be from the time I created the branch to the Head.
5. I made sure both the branch's working copy directory and Trunk's URL were correct.
6. I did a test merge and everything looked ok.
7. Then, I did a merge and committed the changes.

The trunk now has new changes and I want to merge those changes to my branch, however, no changes show up when I do a test merge.

Executing "svn propget svn:mergeinfo ."  in the branch directory shows /myrepo/trunk: 714-740

714 is the revision that created the branch and 740 is a revision of a commit to the branch.  Currently, the most recent commit to the branch is revision 745 and last commit of the merge from the trunk is revision 730 (as shown in the branch's log).  The trunk's most recent commit is revision 736.

Why doesn't test merge show anything to merge?

Comment: Do I understand correctly: You merged changes from your branch and now you want to merge them back from trunk to the same branch?

Comment: Yeti: I merged the changes from the Trunk to the branch (i.e. call it MyBranch) last week.  Now, I want to do a merge from the Trunk to MyBranch again.

Comment: Yeti: The mergeinfo property seems to imply that I have already merged everything from 714 through revision 740. Is that correct?

Comment: Does anyone know the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: Well...I completed the merge from the trunk by selecting ignore ancestry.  However, the mergeinfo still contains the same info.  I am not sure how to correct that issue.

Comment: Has anyone else had the issue with MergeInfo not containing the correct information?